# How do I write generic code for rendering a list \ of meshes that have different geometries with vanilla webgl?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, opengl-es, webgl

I want to render a list of objects with geometries, that needs to be uploaded as attribute once and redrawn each frame.

I have a function that takes a geometry and gives a `draw info object` that includes a webgl program, uniforms, and attributes as vao. \
Later in my render function I can render this draw info.

At initialization time:

```
// an object that is used to load attributes
const aPosInfo = new G.makeBufferInfoForAttribute("aPosition", 2);
// draw info that is used to render with gl.drawarrays
const mesh = g.makeDraw({
  name: 'cube',
  program: 'cube',
  uniforms: {},
  bufferInfos: [
    aPosInfo
  ]
});

// here I upload the attribute buffer with geometry vertices.
aPosInfo.set(geometry, g.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

At render time:

```
// add object to render queue
addToRenderQueue({
  mesh,
  uniforms: {
  }
});
```

The problem here is, I don't have the list of objects until render time so I don't have access to geometries so that I can upload at in\
itialization time. So I might have a flaw in my design of webgl code. So I shall ask; How do I write generic code for rendering a list \
of meshes that have different geometries with webgl?

Comment: I have a feeling your question is to broad. There are 1000s of ways to organize rendering. Generally objects are stored in some data structure (scene graph, oct tree, binary partition space, grid, ...), at render time you go through that structure and either render from it directly or, more common, make a lists of things that need to be drawn. That list might then be sorted for various reasons before finally being iterated over and drawn.

Comment: It's also common to have to do this multiple times for a single frame. For example traditional shadows require drawing things once for each light and you only want to draw the things the light can see and the camera can see which means each list will have a different set of objects. Similarly separating opaque objects from translucent objects is common. There are many ways to do all of this so there's no single answer. Consider looking through the source of a 3D engine like say three.js for an example of one solution.